# PostgreSQL 9.5 Multiple SELECT in SELECT

Tags: postgresql, view

For the information, the general purpose of this question is to be able to work in QGIS with an updatable view system.

Let's say I have a table "building" and a table "apartment". Let's say the tables are defined as such :

```
CREATE TABLE building (
    id_building INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    adress VARCHAR(255)
    );

CREATE TABLE apartment (
    id_apartment INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    floor INTEGER,
    id_building INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (id_building) REFERENCES building (id_building)
    );

INSERT INTO building VALUES (1, 'adress1');
INSERT INTO building VALUES (2, 'adress2');

INSERT INTO apartment VALUES (1, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES (2, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES (3, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES (4, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES (5, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES (6, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES (7, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES (8, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES (9, 0, 2);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES (10, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES (11, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES (12, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO apartment VALUES (13, 2, 2);
```

I would like, in a view of the table building, to display the number of apartment grouped by floor. If it is possible, what would be the way to do so ? And since the number of floors can vary, it would be even better to be able to automatically generate a somehow flexible view relatively to the number of floors of each building.

There is a version of this code here: http://rextester.com/MTIJ52125

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its just that easy:

```
CREATE VIEW apartments AS (
    SELECT 
    building.id_building, 
    apartment.floor,
    count(apartment.id_apartment) as apartments_per_floor
FROM 
    apartment,building 
WHERE 
    building.id_building = apartment.id_building 
GROUP BY apartment.floor, building.id_building, apartment.floor
ORDER BY 1,2
);

SELECT * FROM apartments;
```

Comment: Indeed! Now I just need to figure out how to present that properly in QGIS. Thanks :)